# NaiveBayes: Adding a new predictor which is random noise

Tags: classification, normal-distribution, naive-bayes, noise, bias-variance-tradeoff

In the NaiveBayes method, can adding a random noise vector where each element is sampled from, e.g., a standard normal distribution, help? In what cases this may be a 'clever' approach?

I imagine this would help to break the bias a little bit, but I cannot justify my thoughts.

Comment: Why adding random, independent, i.e. unrelated to your data, noise would help with anything, for any algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

No, it definitely does not help. Not just for Naive Bayes, but for any algorithm, as also noted in the comments. As you've also stated, it is *random*, *unrelated* and doesn't have expressive power over the target variable.